# AWS S3 SDK IOS : Resume uploads after close the app

Tags: swift, aws-sdk

I was working on amazon sdk in a multipart upload and download, and it is not resuming when we close the app and open once again. The uploads or downloads always restart from 0% even I have uploaded more than 5mb.

Is here any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: No, not yet @Bucket.